# An unhandled exception has occured in silver light`

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have create a new `project` by selecting `Silverlight` project but I am getting the error as

An unhandled exception has occured

[image]

How to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved for me. Check by Control panel, Programs all the installed Silverlight programs.

If you installed **Silverlight 4**, then check for **Microsoft Silverlight** in control panel uninstall programs (Silverlight Developer runtime) by selecting the row

It would not be the version higher like 5.0.00.. (You can see on bottom status)

If so (5.0), uninstall **Microsoft Silverlight** (5.0 version)

Download [Silverlight 4 Developer Runtime v4.0.50524.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/8/C5877489-8022-42A6-8456-D05C2A6C8DFB/runtime/Silverlight_Developer.exe).

and install it, then open your project. it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You develop SL 4 on VS2008? VS 2008 don't support preview xaml
2. You need to upgrade to VS2010 to use SL 4 better.
3. Is what is likely happening is that you have the standard version of the Silverlight runtime and you need to install the developer runtime for Silverlight. Blend will install and run with the standard verison of the silverlight runtime, but Visual Studio requires the developer version of the runtime. This issue is fixed in the RTM version of Visual Studio.

   For now, if you hit this issue, please install the silverlight developer runtime from this link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=146060
4. Here is a similar case, maybe it will give you some helps:

   http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2009/06/08/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-in-a-net-application.aspx

If above doesn't give you helps, it's better that you can zip up your code for us so that we can test it.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010